# Kotlin Android allow only emojis and letters in a text

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

I've been trying to find a good way to be able to keep only emojis and letters in a given text, but every article I found, I didn't have success with .
I've tried to use regex, but seems that I can not make it work.
I've tried to use [emoji4j](https://github.com/kcthota/emoji4j) but it seems that this library is working with emojis in this form ":)", which don't help me, because my emojis are groups of unicode characters.

The result I want is the following :

```
"This is. a text ‍‍‍,,1234" => "This is a text ‍‍‍"
"‍‍‍" => "‍‍‍"
"‍‍‍123abc‍‍‍" => "‍‍‍abc‍‍‍"
```

Here's the emoji regex :  `?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:[\ud83c\udde6-\ud83c\uddff]){2}|[\ud800\udc00-\uDBFF\uDFFF]|[\u2600-\u26FF])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|[\ud83c\udffb-\ud83c\udfff])?(?:\u200d(?:[^\ud800-\udfff]|(?:[\ud83c\udde6-\ud83c\uddff]){2}|[\ud800\udc00-\uDBFF\uDFFF]|[\u2600-\u26FF])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|[\ud83c\udffb-\ud83c\udfff])?)*|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|[\ud83c\udd70-\ud83c\udd71]|[\ud83c\udd7e-\ud83c\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|[\ud83c\udd91-\ud83c\udd9a]|[\ud83c\udde6-\ud83c\uddff]|[\ud83c\ude01-\ud83c\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|[\ud83c\ude32-\ud83c\ude3a]|[\ud83c\ude50-\ud83c\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff]` .

If I try something like :

`val regex = "the_whole_regex_above | [^a-zA-Z]".toRegex()
myText.replace(regex,"")`, it won't replace anything, basically every character will pass

Basically I want to achieve pretty much the same thing as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101243/how-to-remove-everything-except-words-and-emoji-from-text), but using Kotlin.

Comment: for example : "This is. a text ‍‍‍,,1234" . it will return the same text. ("This is. a text ‍‍‍,,1234")

Comment: I feel that all you need is to remove all punctuation, symbols (other than those used to form emojis) and digits, right? Try `myText.replace("""[\p{N}\p{P}\p{S}&&[^\p{So}]]+""".toRegex(), "")`

Comment: I'm sorry for unclarities . so what I want is : "This is. a text ‍‍‍,,1234" to return "This is a text ‍‍‍"

Comment: See https://ideone.com/koXAWG

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your answer is right. Works as expected.

Comment: `keep only emojis and letters` yes ? i give yuo this if wanter. note these other links and answer downt desrcibe emoji which is a complex regex. let me know

Answer (score 2):

You want to remove all punctuation, symbols (other than those used to form emojis) and digits.

To do that, you may use

```
myText = myText.replace("""[\p{N}\p{P}\p{S}&&[^\p{So}]]+""".toRegex(), "")
```

See the [online Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/koXAWG).

**Details**

- `[` - start of a character class that matches:

  - `\p{N}` - any Unicode digit
  - `\p{P}` - any Unicode punctuation proper
  - `\p{S}` - any Unicode symbol
  - `&&[^\p{So}]` - BUT the Unicode symbols belonging to Symbol, other Unicode category that are mostly used to form emojis
- `]+` - 1 or more occurrences.

Comment: there's a problem with this: symbols like  ®  pass the filter.

Comment: @biafas Correct, that char is in the [Symbol, Other](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/So) category. There are some chars in that category that are not used to form emojis. You may add those frequent ones to the regex, `[\p{N}\p{P}\p{S}¦©®°҂&&[^\p{So}]]+`. The precise solution is to use a huge regex encompassing the whole emoji list.

Comment: isn't there a way to use that huge regex I posted in the original question?

Comment: @biafas Yes, do you just want to use that one to match only those emojis it matches? It does not match all of them.

Comment: well I'd prefer to use a regex that matches all emojis. I thought this is the right one

Comment: @biafas [This one does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48148218/3832970), but it requires an update that I can't make for the time being.

Comment: how will this work in conjuction with only letters? Thats the biggest problem I'm facing. I don't know how to combine this long Regex expression with allowing only letters

Comment: @biafas Whatever pattern with Unicode escape sequences I try to match an emoji there is no match. If you know how to make your pattern match an emoji, then all you need is `myText.replace("((?:\\p{L}\\p{M}*+|$emojiPattern)+)|\\S".toRegex(), "$1")`